# Fixed last argument with xargs

Tags: xargs

Is it possible to use xargs to invoke a command so that the last argument of the command is fixed?

My attempt:

```
printf '%s\n' a b c d | xargs -I{} echo {} LAST
```

ends up doing

```
echo a LAST  
echo b LAST  
echo c LAST  
echo d LAST
```

I want for xargs to invoke

```
echo a b c d LAST
#fit as many as you can but always finish wiht LAST
```

Is this possible to do, preferably in a portable way?

Comment: not as far as I known but at least `cp`, `mv` and `ln` commands havs a `-t|--target-directory` parameter that replace the last arg...

Comment: Would you please shed more light on what you want. i mean revise the question and add more clarifications. In the current shape it is not clear!

Comment: Also, the output of your command is empty lines.

Comment: @Goro Thanks had copied it wrong. I think it should be clear now what I'm trying to do. The `echo a b c d LAST` should get assembled from the input (stdin) though it could well generate `echo a b LAST` `echo c d LAST` if MAX_ARG was really small.  The point is the stuff between echo and LAST must come from the input and it should contain as many items as possible.

Comment: Your command still doesn't work! "xargs: LAST: No such file or directory"

Comment: Are you sure it's not working for you? `printf '%s\n' a b c d | xargs -I{} echo {} LAST` does work for me (producing the `a LAST` `b LAST`, etc.)

Comment: Yes! it didn't work . I use Centos 7

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**tl;dr;** this is how you could do it portably, without `-I` and other broken fancy options:

```
$ echo a b c d f g | xargs -n 2 sh -c 'echo "$@" LAST' sh
a b LAST
c d LAST
f g LAST

$ seq 1 100000 | xargs sh -c 'echo "$#" LAST' sh
23692 LAST
21841 LAST
21841 LAST
21841 LAST
10785 LAST
```

The problem with the `-I` option is that it's broken by design, and there is no way around it:

```
$ echo a b c d f g | xargs -I {} -n 1 echo {} LAST
a b c d f g LAST
$ echo a b c d f g | xargs -I {} -n 2 echo {} LAST
{} LAST a b
{} LAST c d
{} LAST f g
```

But they're probably covered, because that's what the standard says:

> -I  replstr
> ^[XSI] [Option Start] Insert mode: utility is executed **for each
> line from standard input**, **taking the entire line as a single
> argument**, inserting it in arguments for each occurrence of
> replstr.

And it doesn't say anything about the interaction with the `-n` and `-d` options, so they're free to do whatever they please.

This is how it is on an (older) FreeBSD, less unexpected but non-standard:

```
fzu$ echo a b c d f g | xargs -I {} -n 2 echo {} LAST
a b LAST
c d LAST
f g LAST
fzu$ echo a b c d f g | xargs -I {} -n 1 echo {} LAST
a LAST
b LAST
c LAST
d LAST
f LAST
g LAST
```

Comment: I can't help thinking there could be a more neutral way of phrasing this answer. It also feels odd to point out one OS in particular (Linux), when you seem to be of the opinion that it's the behaviour required by the standard that's at fault here.

Comment: could you please explain why do we need to invoke sh again at the end of that command?

Comment: @CarlosMendoza if you mean the `sh` after the `-c '...'` that's not invoking anything it's just setting `argv[0]`/`$0`; you can replace it with `argv0` or anything you like. Without it, the echo wouln't have echoed its 1st argument. To get the idea, try `sh -c 'echo "$@"' argv0 1 2 3` without `argv0`.

Answer (score -2):

Not with `xargs` (alone). If you have an item list of unpredictable length, how should `xargs` know from the beginning (= first element) which element would be the last one?
You'll need some additional logics around it to separate the desired element from the others.

Comment: @ilkkachu: Then, please show how from the list `a b c d LAST` to get to four parameter lists `a LAST`, `b LAST`, `c LAST`, and `d LAST` by using `xargs` alone without the constant `LAST` being supplied by other means (as wrongly done above). If that is what the requestor wanted.

Comment: I thought they wanted to go from `a b c d` to `a b ... LAST`, or such, with more than one of `a`, `b`, etc used by `xargs` for each command invocation. (one is easy, that's what `-I` does.) They did specify the `LAST` part in the `xargs` command (not in the `printf` feeding `xargs`), it's just that it doesn't work like that with `-I` (but does in FreeBSD `xargs -J`). But yeah, you're right in that I misread your intent, though technically`xargs` could read the whole input before processing, but that wouldn't be very efficient.

Comment: Now that I reread the original request, I admit I may have misread it, so the base of my approach is gone...