# Trouble understanding gsettings + xargs behaviour

Tags: xargs, gsettings

To set the stage, I have this 2 equivalent and working 'xargs' composed commands, in this sample echo scenario:

```
// ok
$ echo org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm move-to-workspace-5 | xargs echo
org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm move-to-workspace-5

// ok
$ echo org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm move-to-workspace-5 | xargs -I '{}' echo '{}'
org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm move-to-workspace-5
```

Now, when I replace the 'echo' command with 'gsettings get' the second case fails:

```
// ok
$ echo org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm move-to-workspace-5 | xargs gsettings get
['<Alt>F4']

// fails
$ echo org.cinnamon.desktop.keybindings.wm move-to-workspace-5 | xargs -I '{}' gsettings get '{}'
Usage:
  gsettings [--schemadir SCHEMADIR] get SCHEMA[:PATH] KEY

  Get the value of KEY

 Arguments:
   SCHEMADIR A directory to search for additional schemas
   SCHEMA    The name of the schema
   PATH      The path, for relocatable schemas
   KEY       The key within the schema
```

What is going on and how can I get more visibility in the issue?

Comment: also see my ranting about `xargs -I` [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466266/308316)

Comment: `-I {}` gives me flashbacks to the horror that is `find`'s horrid stuff. I have found that `-I_` or `-IXXX` are easier to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-I {}` options of `xargs` will cause it to pass a whole line from the input as a single argument.

This is what the manpage of xargs(1) says:

> -I replace-str
>
> Replace occurrences of replace-str in the initial-arguments with
>                 names  read  from  standard input.  Also, **unquoted blanks do not
>                 terminate input items**; instead  **the  separator  is  the  newline
>                 character**.  Implies -x and **-L 1**.

You can easily see the difference by using an arguments printing script instead of `gsettings`:

```
$ cat /tmp/a
#! /bin/sh
echo -n "$0"; for a; do echo -n " {$a}"; done; echo
$ chmod 755 /tmp/a

$ echo foo bar | xargs /tmp/a
/tmp/a {foo} {bar}

$ echo foo bar | xargs -I '{}' /tmp/a '{}'
/tmp/a {foo bar}
```

What to do next depends on what you want to achieve with those commands.