# Using xargs -n and -I together

Tags: bash, pipe, xargs

I have 600 files I wanted to copy to S3. Wanted to do it in batches of 10, so I wrote:

```
$ ls -1 | xargs -ILST -n 10 echo s3 cp LST xx
s3 cp LST xx f9b3ac7e-3683-42dd-aed3-41b36bcf822c f9c30a0d-c196-4f2c-9ed6-522884191070 fa6d8590-872a-40e3-861d-22de247acaf6 fa71a0dd-7e88-4ecb-8e66-56c17776112a fac23a2c-6c5f-4c6a-be33-68b16bfaa82b fb04b6ac-3e7b-4239-988c-d58110c18013 fb06015a-e1b4-4c6d-b5e8-f0216756887d fb078c75-e0a3-498d-a8a6-c34c46160a9b fb6752f7-54b9-4683-99df-6d4abce95a8d fb6f02e7-35fb-477c-8f9b-a0bde4aeebbd
s3 cp LST xx fbcd90f5-b4af-49ff-913f-8d173402806e fbf7a1e9-0b53-4f14-96ad-ebc83364c13a fbfe2b17-8694-4e27-9de8-95e46935d142 fc17155d-691c-4241-9a52-8fc2d41412d5 fe4f7de0-06fe-4063-9516-feca8210e3ad fe81ab02-91c0-4dbe-b298-5b17f39fe9db fe911d6a-84ff-40e1-9884-36b307b36779 ff238e7c-d48a-4957-9016-c0ed729856dd ff6827cd-2ce7-42ae-a6a4-a62da0c2a97a ff9594b3-23e5-42a8-a41c-a742b1a33db8
......
$
```

If works fine if we use only `-I` or `-n`

```
$ ls -1 | xargs -ILST echo s3 cp LST xx
s3 cp fe81ab02-91c0-4dbe-b298-5b17f39fe9db xx
s3 cp fe911d6a-84ff-40e1-9884-36b307b36779 xx
s3 cp ff238e7c-d48a-4957-9016-c0ed729856dd xx
s3 cp ff6827cd-2ce7-42ae-a6a4-a62da0c2a97a xx
s3 cp ff9594b3-23e5-42a8-a41c-a742b1a33db8 xx
......
$
$ ls -1 | xargs -n 10 echo
f9b3ac7e-3683-42dd-aed3-41b36bcf822c f9c30a0d-c196-4f2c-9ed6-522884191070 fa6d8590-872a-40e3-861d-22de247acaf6 fa71a0dd-7e88-4ecb-8e66-56c17776112a fac23a2c-6c5f-4c6a-be33-68b16bfaa82b fb04b6ac-3e7b-4239-988c-d58110c18013 fb06015a-e1b4-4c6d-b5e8-f0216756887d fb078c75-e0a3-498d-a8a6-c34c46160a9b fb6752f7-54b9-4683-99df-6d4abce95a8d fb6f02e7-35fb-477c-8f9b-a0bde4aeebbd
fbcd90f5-b4af-49ff-913f-8d173402806e fbf7a1e9-0b53-4f14-96ad-ebc83364c13a fbfe2b17-8694-4e27-9de8-95e46935d142 fc17155d-691c-4241-9a52-8fc2d41412d5 fe4f7de0-06fe-4063-9516-feca8210e3ad fe81ab02-91c0-4dbe-b298-5b17f39fe9db fe911d6a-84ff-40e1-9884-36b307b36779 ff238e7c-d48a-4957-9016-c0ed729856dd ff6827cd-2ce7-42ae-a6a4-a62da0c2a97a ff9594b3-23e5-42a8-a41c-a742b1a33db8
......
$
```

Am I doing something wrong or it's just not possible to use `-I`and `-n` at the same time? man page doesn't say anything.

I'll remove `echo` in the final product of course. `xx` is the target s3 folder placeholder.

Comment: You can't use `-n` and `-I` together. See also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/485072/why-does-xargs-n-on-smartos-sunos-behave-differently-than-other-implementa/485075#485075) and the other answers linked from there (especially [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/466266/308316))

Comment: @don_crissti I did see the man page before posting, I wasn't trying to use `-x` or `-L` with `-I`. I was trying `-n`. man page could've been as explicit as the spec referred to in links you and mosvy provided. Thanks!